# getUrl using my original develpment server domain

Tags: templating, url, htaccess

I have the following code and after moving site to a live server, the img src is using the old domain, however, the anchor links have correct domain name.  Any idea what the issue is?

```
                                {% for block in entry.threeHomepageImages.type('images') %}
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="image-block">
                                            <div class="image">
                                                {% if block.image|length %}
                                                    <a href="{{ block.pageLink.first().getUrl() }}"><img src="{{ block.image.first.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ block.alt }}"></a>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <h1><a href="{{ block.pageLink.first().getUrl() }}">{{ block.imageTitle }}</a></h1>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the path of the asset source the image is in? Sounds like that might still be the old server's path.
Best practice is to use [Environment-specific variables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables) in your config file, and then use those in you Asset Source settings as well.

So, use {basePath}assets/site as your File System Path for instance (if you've used basePath as a config variable).

That way, it will adapt to whatever environment you're working on.

Comment: Duh. It was the asset url to folder. Thank you for the help.